# FAQ for Interpersonal Skills

Tags: support, faq

## Asking questions

- [What is the Sandbox? How do I use it?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3492)
- [How do I write a good question?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224)
- [Are there any suggested question structures?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3211)

## Answering questions

- [How do I write a good answer?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3266)
- [What are the citation expectations of answers on IPS Stack Exchange?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3583)
- [Why did my answer get deleted?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3192)
- [What is the difference between not answering a question and posting a frame challenge?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2511)
- [Should we allow answers to make potential diagnoses?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1935)

## Comments

- [Does IPS moderate comments differently from the rest of the Network?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3807/)
- [Please don't write answers in comments](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1644)
- [How do you tell an answerer that you think their answer needs work?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2499/)
- [What is the IPS Comment Bot?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3377)

## Moderation

- [How to be a good community moderator while leaving a comment?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3368)
- [Comment Templates](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3262)
- [When should one recommend deletion for a Low Quality Post in the queue?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3320)
- [Should I wait before casting a close vote?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1748)

---

If you didn't find what you needed here, maybe the [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/400547) can help you.